# DataGridView Images not showing up in unbound column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got a DataGridView bound to a DataTable that I'm wanting to add an Avatar column to.  The column is to be unbound.  I'm using the following code to do it:

```
if (MyIcons != null)
{
    DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();

    imageColumn.Name = "Avatar";
    imageColumn.HeaderText = "";
    imageColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;

    ViewRolesDataGrid.Columns.Insert(0, imageColumn);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ViewRolesDataGrid.Rows)
    {
        Guid iconGuid = (Guid)row.Cells["ID_Picture"].Value;

        if (MyIcons.Icons32x32.ContainsKey(iconGuid))
        {
            Image bm = MyIcons.Icons32x32[iconGuid];

            DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells["Avatar"] as DataGridViewImageCell;

            cell.Value = MyIcons.Icons32x32[iconGuid];
        }
    }
}
```

MyIcons is a class containing sets of dictionaries that hash ID_Picture guid from the database to an actual image fetched and cached previously (so I don't have to join with the images table each time I do a query and send the image data back).  I've verified that the MyIcons cache is instantiated OK, and that it contains images.  Image "bm" above contains a 32x32 32 bit bitmap.

When I run my program, the unbound image column is visible in the view, but no images are rendered.  It behaves as if the value is null (DefaultCellStyle.NullValue changes have an effect).  If I do a full join on the images table to make a column that's bound in the DataTable with the image, the image is displayed.

Can anyone spot my error?

Thanks.

Edit:  It doesn't even work if I assign a bitmap to the cell directly, i.e. I still get nothing displayed in that column:

```
cell.Value = Bitmap.FromFile("picture_32x32.png");
```

Comment: Never played with this myself, but this came up in a search (CellFormttingEvent):  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/119222d6-0189-49ab-a01a-c5eeb201723e

Comment: That's a slightly different thing, as it's about modifying it dynamically.  This is more a one-time, setup and forget type thing.  I'm starting to think there might be something wrong with my images... so testing some ideas.

Comment: You should post that "solved" edit into an answer and accept it yourself so this can properly close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: OK Don's link was basically right. It seems you have to do it with the formatting event, as follows:

```
private void ViewRolesDataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewRolesDataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Avatar")
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = ViewRolesDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        Guid iconGuid = (Guid)row.Cells["ID_Picture"].Value;

        Image icon = null;

        if (MyIcons.Icons32x32.ContainsKey(iconGuid))                
        {
            icon = (Image)MyIcons.Icons32x32[iconGuid];
        }

        if(icon != null)
        {
            DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells["Avatar"] as DataGridViewImageCell;

            cell.Value = icon;
        }              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IT IS NOT NECESSARY to have a CellFormatting event handler !
The very simple Sample given in http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-image.htm works PERFECTLY.
First, take care to have a small image  (f.i. 100 x 100 pixels) 
Enlarge "image column" if images are not "displayed".